# Three columns horizontal form resize issue - Bootstrap v2.3.1

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a 3 columns Form (each column will have a label and an input text and it could be multiple rows).

The issue I'm having is there are some cases when the screen is resized and label and field overlaps; also the horizontal scroll bar is displayed, see below:

[image: 3 cols issue]

See HTML sample

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span4">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="input1">
                        Text input
                    </label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" id="input1"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="input2">
                        Text input
                    </label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" id="input2"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="input3">
                        Text input
                    </label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" id="input3"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I've tried using "container", "container-fluid", "row", "row-fluid"
Any hint on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have other responsive features working? It almost seems like maybe the responsive CSS is not included.

Comment: @emptywalls Yes, I do have other responsive features working like two navbar, one column horizontal-forms, etc.  If I resize more my window browser the content aling properly and no scroll bar is displayed. But, I I'd expect a responsive layout where text never overlaps with fields. I read something that I have to use spanX(for example span12) for my input fields.